# Forearm Twist issue in Blender

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm using a 3 bone setup. The main bone is for the arm IK while I have two bones for the forearm twist. I tried using copy rotation and other things but the major problem I'm having is once you hit 180 degrees with a copy rotation or any constraint is the bones freak out and reset. I've also tried using  a "track to" constraint but you cant limit that it seems. I would like to try to use drivers or something that can control bone roll (drastic I know) but there isnt anything online explaining how to do that for bones.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: bump. Does anyone actually know the solution to this?